# Matchings in $G=(V,E)$ be an undirected graph, and let $S,T\subseteq V$ be two sets of vertices with no common neighbors

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an undirected graph, and let $S,T\subseteq V$ be two sets of vertices  with no common neighbors (there can be edges between $S$ and $T$).
We need to show that if there exists a matching in $G$ in which all vertices in $S$ are covered, and also a (Possibly different) matching in which all vertices in $T$ are covered, then there also exists a matching in $G$ in which all vertices in $S \cup  T$ are covered.

Comment: What difficulties are you having with this problem?

Comment: I have no idea to even approach this one..any leads will be appreciated!

Comment: Consider a path on 3 vertices $v-w-z$. Let $S=\{v,w\}$ and $T=\{z\}$ Then $\{(v,w)\}$ is a matching covering all vertices in $S$ and $\{(w,z)\}$ is a matching covering all vertices in $T$, but there is certainly no matching covering all three vertices. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh I just noticed you are working with directed graphs. But what is the definition of a matching in a directed graph? That the edges do not share heads or tails? I suppose the counterexample works in this case as well if you consider $v\rightarrow w\leftarrow z$

Comment: The fact that $(v,w)$ and $(w,z)$ exist means that $w$ is a common neighbor of $S$ and $T$ ...

Comment: So if there is an edge $(s,t)$ between $S$ and $T$, then no vertex in $S$ is adjacent to $s$ and no vertex in $T$ is adjacent to $t$?

Comment: exactly there cannot be a vertx $v \in V$ and $s \in S$ and $t \in T$ s.t $(s,v) \in E$ and $(v,t) \in E$

Comment: What about this: Let $M_s$ and $M_t$ be the two matchings mentioned in the question. what if we look at $M_s \Delta M_t$, the symetric difference. and here we see that every vertex is of degree $0$ or $2$ which means that every componenet is either an even cycle or a vertex with no neighbors. so we build $M$ a matching that covers both $S$ and $T$ by first taking every edge that was both in $M_s$ and in $M_t$. then by looking at the even cycles in $M_s \Delta M_t$ and takign every second edge in that cycle. that would work won't it?